# Floating Point problem using PIC18F4550

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, floating-point

I'm making an obstacle avoiding robot and using the mentioned PIC controller. I'm currently not at the obstacle avoiding part so what i'm doing is writing code to control the movement, e.g. making it go in a rectangular loop. The way it works is that I have made functions for going straight, turning left/right and one for a small 2 second halt on both wheels called pause. In the straight function I pass an RPM value and a Distance, the function then has to figure out how long this velocity has to be maintained to travel the specified distance. It does this by passing the data to a counts_cal function which returns the value of the counts to be used and then the wheel speeds are set and the counts are sent to a timer function to produce the desired timing. Now the problem is that the counts_cal function isn't working and I think its because of the floats I have used and somehow the conversion from float to long isn't producing what its supposed to. The timer function and the rest works since when I directly passed the counts from straight to timer and bypassed the counts_cal, it all worked fine. But bypassing it is not really an option and I need help because I'm out of my depth with this floating point stuff in micro controllers. When i try this code as it is shown here, what happens is that it acts as if there is no delay on the straight and turn left functions but works fine for the pause since I have passed the counts manually there.

***I'm showing code for only the straight function and ignoring the turn_right/left and pause because they are exactly similar in their function.***

**Here is the relevant code part :**

```
//----------FUNCTION DECLARATIONS-----------//

void send_pos_right (int data);              //Transmit sequence to right wheel(forward)
void send_pos_left (int data);               //Transmit sequence to left wheel(forward)
void straight(int rpm, float dist);         //go straight at certain rpms for certain dist
void turn_left(void);                       //make 90 degree left
void turn_right(void);                      //make 90 degree right
void pause(void);                           //halt both wheels for a brief time (2sec)

void timer(unsigned long counts);                 //produces required time delay based on counts
unsigned long counts_cal (int rpm, float dist);   //calculates number of counts required for travel

//..........GLOBAL VARIABLES...........//

float circum = 0.3989823;           //circumference of wheels
float mc = 0.0000512;               //timer period with 256 prescaler
int turning_rpm = 30;               //standard turning velocity
float turning_dist = 0.44;          //distance to make a 90 degree turn

//............MAIN CODE.............//

void main(void)
{

while(1)
{
    straight(60,4);
    pause();
    turn_left();
    pause();

   }
}

void straight(int rpm, float dist)
{
    unsigned long counts = counts_cal(rpm,dist);
    send_pos_right(rpm);
    send_pos_left(rpm);
    timer(counts);
}

void timer(unsigned long counts)
{
    unsigned char loader_H, loader_L;
    int reps = counts/65536;                        //calculates number of complete reloads required
    unsigned long sub_reps = counts-(reps*65536);   //calculates number of counts required after the complete reloads (semi relaod)
    long value = 65536 - sub_reps;                  //calculates value to load into TMR0H & TMR0L for the semi reload
    T0CON = 0x07;                                   //timer off, 256 prescaler

    while(reps>0)                   //performs the number of complete 16bit timer reloads
    {
        TMR0H = 0x00;
        TMR0L = 0x00;
        T0CONbits.TMR0ON=1;
        while(INTCONbits.TMR0IF==0);
        T0CONbits.TMR0ON=0;
        INTCONbits.TMR0IF=0;
        reps-=1;
    }

    if ((reps==0) && (sub_reps>0))  //performs the semi 16bit timer reload
    {
        loader_H = (value&0xFF00)>>8;
        loader_L = (value&0x00FF);
        TMR0H = loader_H;
        TMR0L = loader_L;

        T0CONbits.TMR0ON=1;
        while(INTCONbits.TMR0IF==0);
        T0CONbits.TMR0ON=0;
        INTCONbits.TMR0IF=0;
    }

}

unsigned long counts_cal (int rpm, float dist)
{
    float rps = rpm/60.0;
    float v = circum * rps;
    float t = dist/v;
    float temp = t/mc;
    unsigned long counts = (unsigned long)(temp);
    return(counts);                                 //returns counts which are required to produce desired time delay
}
```

Comment: Is this the free version of XC8? It's been my observation that non-Pro versions of XC8 handle floating point and implement anything in math.h about as well as molasses flows in Minot in January.

Comment: yes it's the free version of XC8 but I can't really get the pro version right now.

Comment: I wouldn't anyway, it's not really worth it. If you really want to get around it, you can choose a vendor that doesn't cripple their already buggy compiler. CCS and MikroC seem to be popular. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Btw, is there any fixed point method of dealing with this specific situation if floating point is not possible ?

Comment: There's always a way to use fixed point. I wouldn't entirely give up hope of somebody having a work around though. We have some PIC experts here.

Comment: Alrighty then i'll probably wait around for one of them to show up *fingers crossed*

Comment: Have you thoroughly tested the function in question? First with a compiler on a PC (where you can use watch windows and printfs), then in simulation or with the debugger?

Comment: I tried to examine it but couldn't do it. Frankly because i don't really know how to. I tried adding different variables in the watchlist and selecting the the simulator in project properties but the variables were appearing to be out of scope

Comment: I ran your code through the simulator and it appears to be working fine. At 5MHz instruction frequency, counts_cal(60,4) took 707us and returned 195812. timer(counts) then took 10.03 seconds. How do you know that counts_cal() isn't working?

Comment: this has a faulty approach for motion control.  this is because anything being moved has mass/inertia.  so starting/stopping is not instantaneous.  Rather such motion rate changes need to be ramped, a straight line ramp will (usually) work, but a besel shaped ramp is much better (I.E. the ramp changes showly at both ends and very quickly in the middle of the ramp

Comment: this line: 'int reps = counts/65536; ' is an integer divide,  if counts is not >= 65535, the result will always be 0.

Comment: the value 65536 is 0x10000  which is a power of 2, so much of that heavy math could be performed via simple shifts, rather than the long/slow multiply and divide operations.

Comment: regarding this line: 'while(INTCONbits.TMR0IF==0);' rather than burning CPU cycles in a while loop, it would be much better (but more complex) to have an interrupt handler enabled for that timer and let the interrupt handler do all the followup work when the time expires.  Infact, except for the initial setup, the interrupt handler could track the number of times the timer had to cycle and the count for the remaining time.  the set a global flag for the rest of the system to use

Comment: when defining float values, append a 'f' on the end of the number otherwise, the number is actually a double that needs conversion to a float

Comment: this line: 'unsigned long counts = (unsigned long)(temp);' is a bit iffy.  suggest using 'unsigned long counts = floorf(temp)

Comment: in general, I would suggest tracking the revolution of the wheel as a method of measuring when to stop moving rather than tracking how many times the timer expires.. this is easy of the wheel is driven by a motor (preferably a stepper motor) or the wheel has a gray code disk and sensor.  This recommendation is because the motion is not directly related to the timer hardware

Comment: @Bruce Abbot .. I don't know how you got the correct answer, I tried it directly on hardware but it only worked when the count values were directly feeded to the timer.. But I have fixed it now and will post how I did it in a little while

Comment: @user3629249 ... I will be using PID control to keep the motion consistent despite the weight and physical constraints... And yes the reps and sub_reps are designed in such a way that reps only tackles if count > 65536 and the lesser part is handled by sub_reps... I also know about the timer approach but opted out of it for now because what I was aiming for right now didn't require it. When I move on to the autonomous control area then timers will be implemented ...

Comment: @user3629249 .. Yes I understand that this is a bad method.. I was actually just trying to just run a the robot in a simple way to detect any initial flaws. And I did actually find that the left wheel was slightly out of alignment so im gonna do a little rpm adjustment to keep it going straight. I also have the QEI module feeding back the velocity except I have yet to utilize it with a PID algorithm. I don't know how to track position yet so I didn't use the position tracking either. I will be now working on all of that stuff

Comment: Hate to be the guy always showing PIC the middle finger, but floating point arithmetic on a PIC18 is probably not a brilliant idea. As far as I'm aware it doesn't have a FPU and it is a very inefficient 8-bitter. So it will generate extremely slow code. Do you even need floating point? Do you do "advanced" things like square roots or trigonometry etc? I see nothing in your code that calls for the use of float.

Comment: Also you have some bugs in this code. Bug: `reps*65536`, int overflow. Bug `0.0` instead of `0.0f`, you don't want to use `double` literals. These bugs suggest that you are uncertain about how type promotion works in C, which means that you _will_ have other type promotion-related bugs in your code as well. I'd recommend a code review, maybe post the working code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ once it's done.

Comment: Apparently SDCC supports the 18F4550. I'd tinkered with it... rather quirky, but it's based on GCC, and GCC has a reputation for tight, fast code. XC8 is notoriously slow and iffy about float precision. I'm not sure if SDCC would be better, but the code overall will definitely be smaller. Rodrigo Almeida created a SDCC toolchain for MPLABX. It works, but is quite limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I sort of figured out how to get this running myself. What I had done previously was this;

```
unsigned long counts_cal (int rpm, float dist)
{
    float rps = rpm/60.0;
    float v = circum * rps;
    float t = dist/v;
    float temp = t/mc;
    unsigned long counts = (unsigned long)(temp);
    return(counts);                                 //returns counts which are required to produce desired time delay

}
```

But then I noticed that floats were causing problems when I equated the floats to ints and I thought it might be due to errors of truncation when converting to int or long, so I tried something a little different and boiled down the first 5 lines into 1 line after some algebraic manipulation and it worked.I think this worked because now all the multiplications are happening before the division and then when the division + conversion does take place, the truncated value has a very forgivable error (off by less than 100 ms from what I've observed).The PWMs are being maintained for the required timing and all is well. The working method was this;

```
unsigned long counts_cal (int rpm, float dist)
{
    unsigned long counts = (dist*60*78125)/(4*circum*rpm);
    return(counts);

}
```

Comment: You can simply it further. Condense all the constants into a single number 2937160.4  (=60*78125/(4*circum), and don't put the calculation result into `counts` (since you do that anyway after returning). Then it can all go on one line like this:- `return((unsigned long)(dist*2937160.4/rpm));`. This is almost twice as fast as your original code!

Comment: @BruceAbbott No need to calculate the numbers in advance, simply make sure that the constants are grouped together and then have the pre-processor do the calculation. Gives far more readable code. `60*78215` for example is never computed in run-time, the compiler will put the number 4692900 in the machine code. Of course you shouldn't be writing "magic numbers" in the source code in the first place, declare them as constants somewhere.